# How to set id and get in next section in the same page using PHP?

Tags: php, html

I need when user will click on anchor tag the id from db will store and in next section it will fetched. I am showing my code below.

```
    <div class="fynd-space-itms">
    <?php
     $classarr = array("item-exhibitation maploc", "item-parking maploc", "item-offices maploc", "item-storage maploc");
    $sql="select * from category order by id desc";
    $catdata=$dbobj->db_get_data($sql);
      $counter=0;
    foreach ($catdata as $v) {
      $id=$v['id'];
     ?>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="<?php echo $classarr[$counter];?>"><?php echo $v['name'] ?></a><!-- activemap1 -->
    </div>
    <?php
        $counter++;
    if($counter==4){
        $counter=0;
    }
    }
    ?>

<button class="btn nextbtnbgdiv open2" type="button">Next <span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span></button>
<div class="fyndspacecategory fyndsheightsubc nano">
<div class="nano-content">
  <?php
    //need id here
  ?>
</div>
</div>
```

Here when user will click on anchor tag the respective id will store and click on `next` button the bottom part of `div` is displaying and I need to get the id here. All code are inside the same page.

Comment: use javascript to deal with your DOM tree elements, this will be better than php;

Comment: @hassan : How to display it in second section. Can you help me to solve this ?

Comment: are you aware with how to use jquery and javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, starting at the fact you want to load data on same page and you don't want to reload the page to get it done, you'll have to use AJAX, but if reloading pages isn't a problem you can get it done without it by using iframes (but that's not a good looking way to get it done).

I'll start assuming that you will use vanilla Javascript to solve this instead of using JQuery for example. So first we'll need to take a look at [fetch js API](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).

So let's start writing some code based on your example:

```
    <div class="fynd-space-itms">
        <?php
           $classarr = array("item-exhibitation maploc", "item-parking maploc", "item-offices maploc", "item-storage maploc");
           $sql="select * from category order by id desc";
           //$catdata=$dbobj->db_get_data($sql);
           $catdata = [["id"=>1,"name"=>"foo"],["id"=>2,"name"=>"bar"],["id"=>3,"name"=>"oxo"]];
           $counter=0;
        ?>
        <?php
        //Using php loops shorthands to get an easier to read code
        foreach ($catdata as $key => $v):
        ?>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
        <button onclick="loadData(<?php echo $v["id"]; ?>);" class="<?php echo $classarr[$counter];?>"><?php echo $v['name'] ?></button><!-- activemap1 -->
        </div>
        <?php
          //Automating your class array index reset at any size
          $counter = ( $key%sizeof($classarr) ) ? $counter+1 : 0 ;
          endforeach;
        ?>

    <div class="fyndspacecategory fyndsheightsubc nano">
    <div class="nano-content" id="content-wrapper">
    </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      function loadData(id){
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append("data",JSON.stringify( {
          id: id
        }));
        var request = new Request('./loadData.php', {
        method: 'POST',
          body: data
        });

        fetch(request).then(function(r) {
          if(r.status != '200'){
            return false;
          }
          r.text().then(function(data){
            document.getElementById('content-wrapper').innerHTML = data;
          });
        });
      }
    </script>
```

When a button is clicked it will send a request to a php script called loadData.php using the fetch API sending a formData including the category id. Remember that fetch returns a promise and you'll have to wait until it gets resolved so we use the method then to execute some function when it done.

fetch promises can be resolved as text, json, and other formats like is explained [here](https://davidwalsh.name/fetch).

Well lets take a look at loadData.php:

```
    <?php
    //some db stuff here
    $data = json_decode($_POST["data"],true);
    $sql="select * from category order where id = ".$data['id'];
    //$data=$dbobj->db_get_data($sql);
    $data = "Some Fancy Data Here";
    print $data;
     ?>
```

Here it is as easy as call your database function and format and print your data as a string to be read by the request. If you want to return an array of data you should want to json_encode the php array and print it.

Hope it helps you!